# Java program exits before thread has finished. How do I make Cucumber-JVM wait for the thread to exit?

Tags: java, multithreading, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I am trying to **create a new thread** in my Cucumber-JVM program, **when I reach a certain BDD step**.

Then, one thread should be doing something, while the original main thread continues running through the cucumber steps.

The program shouldn't exit until all threads have finished.

**The problem I'm running into, is the main program exits before the thread is finished.**

Here is what's happening:

---

## **Output / Problem**

- **Main program** is `RunApiTest`
- The **thread class** is `ThreadedSteps`.

Here is what happens when I run the program:

1. `RunApiTest` starts going through all steps
2. `RunApiTest` gets to "I should receive an email within 5 minutes"
3. `RunApiTest` now creates a thread `ThreadedSteps`, which should sleep for 5 minutes.
4. `ThreadedSteps` starts to sleep for 5 minutes
5. While `ThreadedSteps` is sleeping, `RunApiTest` continues running the rest of the Cucumber BDD steps
6. `RunApiTest` finishes and exits, **without waiting for `ThreadedSteps` to finish**!

**How do I make my program WAIT until my thread is done?**

---

Here is my code

## **Main Cucumber Class**: `RunApiTest`

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin={"pretty"}, glue={"mycompany"}, features={"features/"})
public class RunApiTest {
}
```

## **Cucumber Step to Trigger Thread**: `email_bdd`

```
@Then("^I should receive an email within (\\d+) minutes$")
public void email_bdd(int arg1) throws Throwable {
     Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadedSteps(arg1));
     thread.start();
}
```

## **Thread Class**: `ThreadedSteps`

```
public class ThreadedSteps implements Runnable {

    private int seconds_g;

    public ThreadedSteps(Integer seconds) {
        this.seconds_g = seconds;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Boolean result = waitForSecsUntilGmail(this.seconds_g);
    }

    public void pauseOneMin()
    {
        Thread.sleep(60000);
    }

    public Boolean waitForSecsUntilGmail(Integer seconds)
    {
        long milliseconds = seconds*1000;
        long now = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();
        long end = now+milliseconds;

        while(now<end)
        {
            //do other stuff, too
            pauseOneMin();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

## **Attempt #1**

I tried adding `join()` to my thread, but that halted my main program's execution until the thread was done, then continued executing the rest of the program. This is not what I want, I want the thread to sleep while the main program continues executing.

```
@Then("^I should receive an email within (\\d+) minutes$")
public void email_bdd(int arg1) throws Throwable {
     Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadedSteps(arg1));
     thread.start();
     thread.join();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`thread.join()` does exactly that -- it requires the program to halt execution until that thread has terminated. If you want your main thread to continue doing work, you need to put your `join()` at the bottom of the code. That way, the main thread can complete all of its tasks and **then** wait for your thread.

Comment: Yeah, I added a `@AfterClass` to `RunApiTest` and added `join()` to that, and it runs last, but the result of the step is saved wrong... I think i'm just going to use the maven parellel plugin instead. https://github.com/temyers/cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin